# WebClient DownloadString method works ok locally but not on production server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webclient

I have the following code in my controller:

```
public ActionResult PreviewContent(int id)
{
        var url = Domain + Url.Action("SomeView");
        string html;
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            html = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        }
        return PartialView("Preview", html);
}
```

That code works ok locally but for some reason isn't working on the production server.

I'm getting this error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: what is `Domain` ?. try to log the value of `url ` and see  whether it is a valid url. It should be an absolute url.

Comment: Domain is a property of my controller. I logged the url and is a valid url. I also replace:
    var url = Domain + Url.Action("SomeView");
with some static address to my site and I got the same issue.
that property returns base url of my site.

Comment: If `url` is a valid absolute url, your code should work fine.

Comment: What's a status code in response?

Comment: that's the issue. If I use some static external url like www.google.com works ok. the issue is with the local url in the production site.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `using` and check non-public field with `Response` and its Status Code in debug.

Comment: You might be using a load balancer or something of that type in which case the Domain will not resolve because the server does not know the domain, only the load balancer does. In this case you need to change the domain to the local address of the server.

Comment: I also create a console app using the same code (passing the url of my site) and worked ok.

Comment: @yoliva - did that console app execute on the same server that you are having problems with?

Comment: no, I made the following adjustment to test the code:
I replaced this code:
    var url = Domain + Url.Action("SomeView");
with:
    var url = http://www.sample.com/controller/view

in the production site I still have the issue and in the console app running from my computer works ok.

Comment: You are not getting what I am writing. The domain that points to your server is being resolved before it hits the server  from outside probably by a piece of network hardware. This means that the domain url you are using can not resolve on the server itself. So no matter what you do, if you keep using the outside domain (that is not resolvable on the server) you will continue to have this problem.

Comment: [Here is a picture.](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/images/software-architecture/load-balancing-1.png) The thing that is resolving the domain is that thing in the middle (load balancer). Traffic for resolving the domain to the server is 1 way (outside to inside only). Once behind the load balancer that same domain name will no longer resolve. This is most likely what your problem is.

Comment: ok @Igor, thanks. thanks all for the answers.